# FileVersionInfo.IsDebug returns always false for dll compiled with debug configuration

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll

I am trying to find whether the dll is compiled with debug or not?

For that I have used `FileVersionInfo`.

```
fileVersionInfo = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("sample.dll");
```

but `fileVersionInfo.IsDebug` property always returns false even I built the `dll` with debug configuration.

whereas other dlls are returning true correctly.

Kindly provide proper solution/suggestion to resolve the issue or

provide other API suggestions to return reliable value always.

Comment: That property's value is determined by the [VS_FF_DEBUG flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx) in the version resource.  The odds that it is accurate are quite low, very few programmers bother with getting it set correctly.  Use a telephone to talk to whoever owns that program.

Comment: There is no other API to suggest. There is no way to know that a binary file is built with the "debug" configuration unless that information was embedded into the file at compile or link time. It requires cooperation between the DLL and the client. The method you're using is the standard one, but it requires the author of the DLL to embed version information, as Hans mentioned. I don't think the default project template in MSVC does this for a DLL. If you cannot change the code for the DLL, you are SOL.